# Multithreaded access to Derby database EclipseLink JPA using JTA

Tags: multithreading, jpa, eclipselink, derby, jta

I am trying to persist objects to a Derby database using EclipseLink JPA using the JTA transaction type in a Java Future.

When I am doing this, I am getting the following error:

```
javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException:
Exception Description: No externally managed transaction is currently active for this thread
```

When I try to get a transaction via entityManager.getTransaction(), I get the message that this is not supported for JTA.
Also I tried to use an EntityManagerFactory to create an entityManager, as I read that this version is thread safe. However, I then get the error that EntityManagerFactory can also not be used with JTA.

Persisting these objects on the main thread works perfectly. It is really a problem of the multi threading.

I am persisting the object like `entityManager.persist(object);`

Is there any way of persisting objects into Derby via EclipseLink JTA in another thread than the main thread? 
(Since this is a general question, I think it is not necessary to add sample code.)

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: JTA transactions have to be joined to ... like in http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_5_0/jpa/transactions.html#jta

Comment: Even though it's a general question, posting sample code and being as specific as you can be always helps.